# has_one existing data in form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations

I have two classes

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :rating

end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I have already populated data in the ratings table.

How can I populate the data in ratings table as a select field when Im creating a movie? And also creating the association once the movie is saved?

Is this something that is possible?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the field of the ratings table which you want to populate in the select?

Comment: Hi @Pavan, name which in this case would be something like R, PG... etc

Comment: Do you want to select the data of rating table while creating a new movie?

Comment: @kajal I would like to select the ratings saved in the db

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like:

```
<%= f.select(:rating, Rating.all.collect {|u| [u.name]}, :prompt => 'Select')  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `belongs_to` association on Rating.

And then in your form:

```
<%= 
  f.select(:rating_id, Rating.all.map {|u| [u.name, u.id]}, :prompt => 'Select')  %>
```

UPDATE:
`belongs_to` is the side of association that specifies the foreign key. So from your Sample i figured that a `Movie` can be rated *0* or more times. A `Rating` always is for one `Movie`.

So your models should be:

`class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
end`

Comment: I get the following error when saving the movie `Rating(#70108240012820) expected, got String(#70108173494120)`

Comment: If I do this shouldnt the movie table have a rating_id?

Answer (score 0):

In your Rating model, take  a constant, and also if you have `has_many` you shld have a `belongs_to` in ratings.

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  Ratings = Rating.all.pluck(:id,:name)
end
```

In your Movie form,

```
<%= f.select :rating, Rating::Ratings.map{|rating| [ rating[1], rating[0] ]} %>
```

Take the field name  for which you want to save the ratings for the movie, if its not rating